# Passing a New Object as an Argument: Is it Possible?

Tags: java, object, parameter-passing, instantiation

Is it possible to do the following - allowing for a properly coded constructor:

```
object1.method(new objectType1(argument1, argument2));
```

Here, object1 contains objects of objectType2.

So, consider the following code:

```
portfolio.addInvestment(new StockInvestment(stock, numshares));
```

addInvestment adds an object of type StockInvestment to an ArrayList . So, addInvestment receives an object of type StockInvestment

Comment: Why *wouldn't* it be? Also, you can just try this and have your question answered without waiting.

Comment: At least in C++, yes, it is. If you're looking for a concrete answer for a specific language you're going to need to tell us what that language is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly normal in Java